# Show image on hover and grey out background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table of items and when I hover over one of them an image should show. The background/ remaining part of the page should be grey out and the image should be shown in the center.
This is what I currently have:

CODE:

```js
function imageAppear(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
}

function imageDisappear(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
.tool {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-left: 20px
}

.tool td {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
    border-color: black;
}

.tool .border {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    ;
    border-color: inherit;
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<table class="tool">
    <tr>
        <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('ocr')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('ocr')">OCR<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" id="ocr" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;" /></td>
        <td class="border" onmouseover="imageAppear('fe')" onmouseout="imageDisappear('fe')">FE<img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/posts/NbYbNrs.png" id="fe" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This works, so that once I hover an item the specific image shows. But how could I position the image in the center of the screen and grey out the background besides the image? And when I remove the cursor from the element to scroll down within the image, the image obviously disappears. Is there a workaround for that, too?
I already tried something like shown [here](https://www.askingbox.com/tutorial/darken-background-of-a-website-gray-out-effect), but with no luck.

Also, the images are really long where you need to scroll down. The problem here is that the webpage generates a large white space at the bottom, even if there is no image currently shown. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to introduce a `wrapper` to the table and a new `light-box` element to grey out the background, with the following styles.

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

and

```
.light-box{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Also, new styles (highly recommend to move these inline styles to a css file) are added to the `img` to make it center aligned.

```
style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: hidden;"
```

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/oKvOyK) link. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works with the background! However, two things: All the page content is greyed out, besides the table itself containing the element showing the image. I tried using different z-index values for the wrapper and table, but couldn't figure it out. Also, the images start at the top, but I want the images to start at the current scroll position (the table is in the middle of the page). And is it possible to be able to scroll down these images? Since I can't leave the cursor from the table cell I can't move to the image first and scroll or scroll in general.